# Advance search in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, search

```
    public function searchAction(Request $request)  
{    
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $searchName = $request->query->get('search_name');
    $searches= \explode(' ', $searchName); 
    $search = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('c')
                    ->from('SavvyContactBundle:Contact',  'c')
                    ->where("c.name = :name")
                    ->setParameter('name', $searchName )
                    ->addOrderBy('c.id', 'DESC')
                    ->getQuery(); 

    return $this->render('SavvyContactBundle:Contact:list.html.twig', array('search' => $search, 'searches' => $searches));
}
```

This is the basic search for specific words and I want to make advance search like Search every single words which imputed in input field so please help and let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Could you give me some feedback please?

Comment: sorry I forget you but your code is working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing from my cellphone, but you got the idea right?

```
...

$words = explode(' ', $searchName);

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('SavvyContactBundle:Contact', 'c')
    ->addOrderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

foreach ($words as $word) {

    $qb
        ->orWhere("c.name = :word")
        ->setParameter('word', $word);
}

$contacts = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

...
```